# How to Speed Up For-Loop with GPU using User-Defined Functions and Lambda Functions

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, parallel-processing, gpu

I am trying to implement a machine learning algorithm in Python from scratch. There is a part of the algorithm where I have to evaluate the error of the function over the entire dataset (~28,000 input vectors) of which I was using a basic *for-loop* as a part of list comprehension to evaluate the classifier and compute how many it gets right. It looks like the following:

```
def computeClassifer(parameters):
    alpha, d = computeAlphaD(parameters)
    return lambda X: sign(sum([alpha[i] * y_train[i] * computeKernel(d, kernels, X_train[i], X) for i in range(len(alpha))]))
def computeError(clf, X_train, y_train):
    return 1 - np.sum([clf(X_train[i]) == y_train[i] for i in range(len(X_train))/len(y_train)
```

right now the biggest problem I am having is runtime, as it takes an obscenely long time to compute the error. I have attempted to parallelize `computeError` function using **Ray** but it still runs slow. I also tried using **numba** but unfortunately I kept running into errors since my `computeClassifer` function returns a lambda function.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, so that the runtime is not super long, preferably using GPU?

Let me add that `kernels` is a list of lambda functions that take in an array of feature vectors and spits out a corresponding kernel matrix.

Comment: are you sure numba doesn't work because you're returning a lambda? This simple  example works: ```@nb.njit
def idk(x):
    return lambda x: x```. Are you sure it isn't because numba doesn't know what ```computeAlphaD```, ```sign``` and ```computeKernel``` are?

Comment: @Nin17 `Cannot capture the non-constant value associated with variable 'X_train' in a function that will escape.` and it points to the return lambda function portion of the code. I just assumed it had something to do with the lambda function.

Comment: In the example of Nin17, this is a basic lambda but in the question, this is a closure. Closure are much more complex to deal with because they need to access to the context to the parent function but in your case, the closure is escaping the context so it is even more complex for a JIT. The basic solution is to create a temporary structure/class for the closure which keep the context and use a virtual-call/function-pointer so to abstract the call. Due to the escape (and the dynamic nature of Python), the context should typically be copied which is clearly inefficient.

Comment: There is no way you can run this efficiently on a GPU without changing the drastically logic of the code. GPUs are not just CPUs with more core, the GPU programming is pretty different and you cannot just run generic code on them (at least not efficiently and speed is the main goal of  using a GPU). The first thing to do is to rewrite your code with basic function and forget about fancy features like closures. Then, you can optimize the code on a CPU and only then, you can think about using GPUs.